# Visual Studio Project rearrange project into folder with same name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, project, solution

Project name is `testProject`. I want to create a new folder named "TestProject" and move the project into it, because I want to add `testProject.uTest` and `testProject.iTest` for unit and integration tests. So everything related is located in the same folder.

The solution is in VSTS. Already one folder exists with the same name because of the project. Namespaces will all change.

How do I go about this the best way?

Comment: You throw away your solution file, rearrange and rename everything how you want it on disk, then create a new blank solution, create whatever folder structure you want in your solution (should match what you create on disk, it makes things less confusing) and re-add the existing projects to it.  There is no magic. There is no easy way. There is only suffering and lamentation.

Comment: Abbreviations only mean something to the person that created them. Just use the full names (i.e "unit" and "integration").

Comment: @Will This is a solution with nearly 100 projects. That's not an option unfortunately...

Comment: Yes, it is an option. It's always an option. You could have been done with it by now, if you had started working on it when you first encountered the problem. You could script it, use find/replace on the solution file, but you still have to put a fair bit of work into that as well.

Comment: And I will have to do that for every project that right now lacks testing. I will be finished in 1-2 weeks. There must be another solution. Why is it so hard to move around existing projects....?

Comment: What's the original structure of your projects in VSTS and what's the detail structure you want? Provide the sample to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got everything to work.

First I opened the solution and deleted the project in there. Then I created the new folder in the solution explorer. I then copied all the project related files into the new folder in windows explorer. I opened up the solution and added this existing project and add all files to source contrl. Next I had to re-add nuget packages and fix some references in other projects. Next I pushed the changes and then I deleted the old project files in source control explorer.

Took 10mins and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

A few simple steps that worked for me:

1. Create a folder and add some text/number at the end:
   Example: `Infrastructure1`
2. Create/Add the Project to your solution without the text/number at the end.
   Example: `Infrastructure`
3. Rename the folder (`Infrastructure1`) to match your Project name(`Infrastructure`).

That's it, and you will get rid of the message that Project can't be named with the same name as the folder.